# Giving permissions with BitField number discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

Is it possible to give permissions to a user/role using the bitfield number? i.e. not to use `{ViewChannel: true}` all the time. And give permissions by using bitfield number.

I try to did this, but it didn't work for me (my code):

```
const channelforedit = i.options.getChannel("channel") ?? i.channel;
const userforperms = i.options.getUser("user") ?? i.user;
const permscalculate = i.options.getInteger("perms") ?? 0;
        
const perms = new PermissionsBitField(BigInt(permscalculate));
        

i.guild.channels.cache.get(channelforedit.id).permissionOverwrites.edit(userforperms.id, {
/*This works*/ ViewChannel: true, 
/*This not.*/ perms});

i.reply({content: `Change perms for user <@${userforperms.id}>, on this: ${permscalculate}`, ephemeral: true});
```

Comment: Ok, almost found solution, i can use `i.guild.channels.cache.get(<channelid>).permissionOverwrites.set([...])` but this replacing all permissions in channel on new. So i still searching a solutrion.

Comment: I need to store perms in variable and somehow add them again. But how?
Why did discordjs use that strange method. In `.edit()` we cannot use array or collections but in `.set()` we can. Ugh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution of this one.

```
const bitPermissions = new PermissionsBitField(268550160n);

console.log(bitPermissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels));
// output: true
```

The `.has()` is returning `true` or `false`. With this function, you can check the existence of certain permissions in the bitfield number.

Completed code. Thanks to `Zsolt Meszaros`.

```
const perms = new PermissionsBitField(BigInt(permscalculate));

const submittedPerms = Object.entries(PermissionsBitField.Flags).reduce((obj, [perm, value]) => ({ ...obj, [perm]: perms.has(value) }), {});
    
i.guild.channels.cache.get(channelforedit.id).permissionOverwrites.edit(userforperms.id, submittedPerms);
```

Comment: Yes, looks a bit ugly. But you could use something like this to create a new object with those booleans: 
`const submittedPerms = Object.entries(PermissionsBitField.Flags).reduce((obj, [perm, value]) => ({ ...obj, [perm]: perms.has(value) }), {});` and use it like this: `.permissionOverwrites.edit(userforperms.id, submittedPerms)`.